# Azure Time Trigger java function - not working locally

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Azure time trigger function java -  is not scheduling while running locally in Intellij ,any lead would help...

sample code generated by Intellij is as follows

```java
public class TimerTriggerFunction {

    /**
     * This function will be invoked periodically according to the specified schedule.
     */
    @FunctionName("TimerTrigger-Java")
    public void run(
        @TimerTrigger(name = "timerInfo", schedule = "0 */5 * * * *") String timerInfo,
        final ExecutionContext context) {
        context.getLogger().info("Java Timer trigger function executed at: " + LocalDateTime.now());
    }
}
```

logs:

The listener for function 'Functions.TimerTrigger-Java' was unable to start. Azure.Core: Retry failed after 6 tries.
Retry settings can be adjusted in ClientOptions.
Retry.
(No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (127.0.0.1:10000)) (No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (127.0.0.1:10000))

Comment: I used this to test locally public async Task Run([TimerTrigger("0 5 * * * *", RunOnStartup = true)] I also used azurite as I think I had similar problems when it wasn't running

Comment: @codebrane TimerTrigger annotation is not taking RunOnStartup param , I feel scheduler is started but not able to find the listener port . I have also mentioned  "LocalHttpPort": 7071 in loca.settings.json.

Comment: the local port is provided by azurite https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azurite?tabs=visual-studio

Comment: @codebrane thanks a lot :) installing Azurite resolved the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

The error that you are getting because you have not [installed Azurite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azurite?tabs=npm)  in your local as,

> The Azurite open-source emulator allows you to test your Azure blob,
> queue, and table storage apps locally for free. Switch to using an
> Azure Storage account in the cloud if you're satisfied with how your
> application works locally.

For more information please refer to this Microsoft document: [Create your first Java function in Azure using IntelliJ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-maven-intellij) & this [blog](https://medium.com/cloudfordummies/local-azure-storage-emulation-with-azurite-and-azure-functions-a-dummies-guide-53949f0c1f44)